# Unable to test the value from contract using truffle test

Tags: solidity, truffle, transactions, testing, truffle-test

block builders! I have trouble testing the return value from my contract, because the return uint value is always a "transaction" object (I actually don't really know what that mean)

**Here is the overall picture of what I'm doing:**

I try to create a bank contract that allowing client to enroll to the bank, making deposit and withdraw the deposit. In order to check if the client really enroll successfully, I put 5 ether to the newly enrolled client.

I firstly use `await` and `async` in the `TestContracts.js` to avoid nested callback, but the testing failed since the return value was a `transaction object` instead of `uint`

Then, I take a different approach using `promise.then`. However, it's even more weird, because the `assert` function was not being called at all, so the test always passed given any expected value.

**Implementation of `Bank` contract:**

```
contract Bank {
struct Customer {
    address _address; // address of customer
    uint deposit;
}

address owner;
mapping(address => Customer) public customerList;
uint customerCounter;

constructor() public payable {
    require(msg.value == 30 ether, "Initial funding of 30 ether required for rewards");
    /* Set the owner to the creator of this contract */
    owner = msg.sender;
    customerCounter = 0;
}

function enroll() public returns(uint){
    customerList[msg.sender].deposit = 5;
    customerList[msg.sender]._address = msg.sender;
    customerCounter++;

    return customerList[msg.sender].deposit;
}
```

**Implementation of `TestContracts.js` using `async` and `await`**

```
contract("Test", function(accounts) {
console.log("total accounts: ",accounts);
const alice = accounts[1];
const bob = accounts[2];
const charlie = accounts[3];
it("add 1 people to the bank", async ()=>{
    const bank = await Bank.deployed();
    const aliceBalance = await bank.enroll({from:alice});

    assert.equal(aliceBalance, 5, "initial balance is incorrect");
})
```

**Implementation of `TestContracts.js` using `Promise`**

```
contract("Test", function(accounts) {
console.log("total accounts: ",accounts);
const alice = accounts[1];
const bob = accounts[2];
const charlie = accounts[3];
it("add 1 people to the bank", function(){
    Bank.deployed().then(function(bank){
        return bank.enroll({from:alice})
    }).then(function(balance){
        assert.equal(aliceBalance, 0, "initial balance is incorrect");
    });
    // const aliceBalance = await bank.enroll({from:alice});
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the return data from transactions. It's not included in the tx receipt, which is why calling `enroll()` returns the tx object instead of the data. If you want to get the data it returns, you have to do a call instead of a transaction, using `await bank.enroll.call({from:alice})`. This however wont actually change any state variables of course.

Comment: Thank you! What's a transaction receipt? Does it define what can be returned and what can't be?

Comment: The tx receipt is essentially the record of the outcome of a transaction. The gas used, contract created, succeed/fail status, logs, etc. The tx receipt of every transaction in a block is stored in the receipt tree in the receiptRoot of each block header. It let's you trustlessly receive  tx outcome with only the headers

Comment: omg, thank you so much flygoing. Unfortunately, I can not upvote your answer, but only accept since I do not have enough credit for upvoting. Really thank you!!